# React Native Image getSize in Android sometime not works

Tags: android, react-native

React Native: use one module with using Image.getSize - it's oK in iOS BUT in Android build only some photos (usually created by this device) can get

module: react-native-transformable-image
Use with react-native-lightbox

iOS - OK!
Android - some loading, some just black screen (modal default background), some 'red' Errors, caused if failed Native Image.getSize

Any ideas? Thanks!

**Error:**

```
Error: Pool hard cap violation? Hard cap = 75497472 Used size = 60880784 Free size = 0 Request size = 20072448
```

**Addition:**

Not enough memory! Only when very large Images:
Full HD - only not showing, but without Error, larger cause the error written previously

Comment: I think you should provide examples, what you have done and where your problem is.

Comment: Added some specifications

Comment: I have the same issue on rn 0.36, do you find any workaround for this issue?

Comment: I declined using smth like this and took a WebView